# Removing exact from parent route path is showing both parent and child component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and creating some nested routing in my reactjs application. I was using 'exact' keyword for my HomeComponent but to create a nested routing i had to remove 'exact' from  because if you have 'exact' on parent the child component doesn't render, after removing 'exact' the child component renders  but the problem is that now both parent and child both displaying on the screen.

is there a way to create nested routing in reactjs which shows only current child on the screen?

Thanks for the help.

Sorry i can't post the code here due to security policy of my org.

Comment: You do not need to nest routes. Check out the basic example on the docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo I need nested routing to create a BreadCrumb trail and I am using react-breadcrumbs for that, to make the breadcrumb work i have to have a nested routing and route using match.url so that trail can be generated.